# Magento 1.9.1.0 Deadlock error when saving a product in backend

Tags: magento-1.9

When we try to save the product via backend, we are getting the following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `index_process_event`
>   (`process_id`,`event_id`,`status`) VALUES (?, ?, ? ) ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE `status` = VALUES(`status`)

We checked in database to see any sleeping queries (SHOW PROCESSLIST). But we couldn't find any.

Does anybody came through these types of issues?

Comment: Do you have the cron and indexers enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably product indexers are updating while you save the products from the backend.

When we are updating a large number of products through the backend and the configuration setting of indexers are `Update on Save`, then Magento will perform indexing operations which may lead to such chaos.

So I think you should put the indexer status to `Update by Schedule`. This way your product save won't go through any hassle. After you have done the bulk update, you should run the crons manually (if it is really necessary)

Magento 2 cron jobs also make some issues. At least, I have faced it in Magento 2.2. This is a known issue and is reported in the Git. There are some cool extensions to overcome this.

If you need futher details, please let us know.